# unable to connect to the google cloud instance (port 22: Operation timed out)

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-shell

I had created the the keys for the google cloud instance and when I try to ssh into the instance. I'm unable to access it and getting an error: port 22: Operation timed out. This happens through both the desktop ssh client and also through the google cloud shell. I had created a project wide keys in the metadata section to access it.

Any insights on why I'm unable to connect will be highly helpful. The instance was created a day ago.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the troubleshooting tips [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser).  Given the timeout connecting to port 22, the reason is likely TCP-level.  Check the firewall settings to verify port 22 is open (it should be by default though) and verify sshd is not experiencing any issues by searching for "sshd" through the instance serial console output.

Comment: Hi @Alexey, 

Google seems to have made an update. For pre-built bitnami wordpress instance I'm able to ssh into the instance with only single click. You may close this thread.

Comment: I fall on the same problem, Is there anyone who can help me on how to address that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't figure out why I was not able to ssh into the server previously. But now there is a single click option to ssh into the google cloud instances. You may close this thread.